# Cannot use more than half of total available thread in CPU

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, cpu, parallel.foreach

I am testing a program on a server, which is running 64bit Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, and it has 4 Intel E7-4870 processors, total 40 cores and 80 available threads (I can see the 80 CPU usage graphs in the Windows Task Manager).

The program code is like:

numlist is List contains hundreds of numbers, each one is a parameter to be used in some calculation

```
Parallel.ForEach(numlist, num =>
                 {
                    // do some calculation using parameter = num             
                 });
```

The issue is that when I run this progrm on the server, only half of the available threads are shown to be used in windows task manager (of course CPU usage is shown 50%), and the rest of 40 are all totally unused and idling.

I also tested the same program on another server which only has 2 processors and total 24 available threads, and all 24 threads will be fully used and CPU usage is shown as 100%.

Is there any way I can make the 40 core - CPU server to run this program and fully utilized all its avaialble 80 threads (or close to 80 threads)? The performance is not good enough when only 50% of CPU resource is used.

---

Here is the full program code I am testing:

```
namespace Test
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to start");
            Console.ReadLine();
            List<int> numlist = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                numlist.Add(i);
            }

            Parallel.ForEach(numlist, num =>
                                 {
                                 while (true)
                                 {
                                     num++;
                                 }
                             });

        }
    }
}
```

when it is run on a server with 2 Intel X5690 processors (total 24 threads available), all of the 24 threads are used and CPU usage is shown as 100%;

But when I run it on the 4 processors server with 80 threads available, only 40 of the threads are used and CPU usage is only 50%. Is there any compiler settings related to this?

Comment: Are you sure you have more than 40 numbers? There really isn't much information here, it will be difficult to figure out the problem.

Comment: Yes, to make up the numlist, I put this code before the parallel loop:       List<int> numlist = new List<int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                numlist.Add(i);
            }

Comment: Try using `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` in `ParalellOptions`

Comment: I tried, MaxDegreeOfParallelism does not help. I even created two Task object, each of them contains a parallel.foreach loop, and start the two tasks at the same time inside the program. CPU usage is still 50% and only half threads are used.

Comment: To clarify, I found this issue by, I am writing a large windows service system, and there are complicated business logic inside the parallel loop. I tested the service on different servers and found this issue. So I wrote the above small test. From test result, it looks like this issue is not related to the content inside the parallel loop, just the c# compiler determined "40 core 80 threads are too much for a single exe process" by itself.

Comment: @CMinusGuy It has nothing to do with that - it's purely a matter of the type of work you're doing, and your system architecture.  *Your system is really a 40 core system*, the fact that it's advertised as 80 threads is really misleading if you're doing CPU heavy work.  You're saturating the 40 cores - the fact that you're at nearly exactly 50% CPU typically means you are *fully utilizing your hardware* to the best of the ability given your algorithm.  This is common in heavily computational workloads with hyperthreaded systems.

Comment: Try manually spawning with `new Thread()` the threads, so it's clear if it's a problem of `Parallel.ForEach` or of hyperthreading.

Answer (score 9):

Depending on the type of work, [hyper threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) does not always help.  With many types of pure math operations, each core can only process one work item effectively, not 2 as suggested by the processor "thread count".

Hyper threads aren't actually separate cores, so the instructions that run on them do not always lead to gains.  This is [discussed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading#Performance_claims):

> Depending on the cluster configuration and, most importantly, the nature of the application running on the cluster, performance gains can vary or even be negative. The next step is to use performance tools to understand what areas contribute to performance gains and what areas contribute to performance degradation.

Hyper threading tends to lead to around a 30% increase in overall performance *in the best case*.  For this to work, you typically need different CPU instructions pushing through each thread on the core, so the core can perform the work properly.  When running the same calculation in parallel across many hyper threaded "CPU threads", you often will see no advantage vs. one process running per core.

This may also be due to the fact that you're using managed code, which is going to be limited to processor group 0, as the CLR doesn't use the new NUMA instructions in Windows 2008 R2.  As such, if your system is setup so processor group 0 is 40 processors, and the other 40 are split into processor group 1, you may be saturating the entire first processor group with this process.  For details, see [How to Get Started with Multi-Core: Parallel Processing You Can Use](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usisvde/archive/2009/10/24/how-to-get-started-with-multi-core-parallel-processing-you-can-use.aspx).

Comment: Yes I understand the variances of performance in this situation, but my main concern is, why on the 2 processor 24 thread server, all threads are fully utilized; but on the 4 processor 80 thread server, only half are utilized? Does .Net compiler "think" 80 threads is too much for my program?

Comment: @CMinusGuy It's very difficult to tell without seeing your work, but it may be that the "24 thread server" is 2, 12 core processors, where your "80 thread server" is 4, 10 core processors which are hyperthreaded.

Comment: @CMinusGuy Just edited to link to another article.  Your system may have the processor group setup to only use 40 procs, not the potential 64, when using managed code.

Comment: How can I check whether my system's settings related to how many processor group should be used for managed code? Thanks!

Comment: @CMinusGuy I don't think you can in managed code - you'd need to drop to native, and use the NUMA's APIs to see how it's setup.  I suspect that's the problem, though (C# can never use more than 64 processors, but that relies on the system having them in one processor group)

Comment: @CMinusGuy CoreInfo from SysInternals will tell you how the system is organized: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx

Comment: @ReedCopsey, you may be right about HT performance, but this quote is dubious at best. This quote from wikipedia refers to a work from 2002 (even wiki states that this applied "in the beginning" [of HT era]). Looking at the article it quotes degradation for some benchmarks that are heavy on inter-thread communication, so adding more threads may well pass the point of diminishing return. In fact, I would be surprised to find real benchmarks that can repeatedly lose on modern CPUs due to HT. If such exist, I'd wager it's due to memory BW bottlenecks, or poor parallelization, not instruction mix.